# How to get all parent menu items' titles of the current node?

Tags: 8

I know I can load the node's menu item like so:

```
$node_id = $node->id();
$menu_link_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.link');
$result = $menu_link_manager->loadLinksByRoute('entity.node.canonical', array('node' => $node_id));
```

But to use a menu structure in a breadcrumb I need to load all parent menu items. I feel like the menu service provides such a function but I dont get anything out of the documentation. [This here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2226481) seems pretty mighty but it really lacks documentation.

Edit: I've already came this far:

```
$node_id = $node->id();
$menu_link_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.link');
$menu_link = $menu_link_manager->loadLinksByRoute('entity.node.canonical', array('node' => $node_id));

if (is_array($menu_link) && count($menu_link)) {
  $menu_link = reset($menu_link);
  if ($menu_link->getParent()) {
    $parents = $menu_link_manager->getParentIds($menu_link->getParent());
    dpm($parents);
  }
}
```

and it gives me:

```
Array
(
  [menu_link_content:2fd24ddd-19e2-4e8f-9764-839b3f51139e] => menu_link_content:2fd24ddd-19e2-4e8f-9764-839b3f51139e
  [menu_link_content:e30b827f-bc67-4892-b23f-28b23188ffd4] => menu_link_content:e30b827f-bc67-4892-b23f-28b23188ffd4
)
```

Is there an easy way to get those titles?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even shorter using the [MenuActiveTrailInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21MenuActiveTrailInterface.php/interface/MenuActiveTrailInterface/8.2.x).

```
$node_id = $node->id();
$menu_link_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.link');
$menu_link = $menu_link_manager->loadLinksByRoute('entity.node.canonical', array('node' => $node_id));
$currentPluginId = $menu_link->getPluginId();
$trailIds = $this->menuActiveTrail->getActiveTrailIds('main');

foreach (array_reverse($trailIds) as $key => $value) {
  if ($value && $value !== $currentPluginId) {
    $breadcrumb->addLink(
      new Link(
        $menu_link_manager->createInstance($value)->getTitle(),
        $menu_link_manager->createInstance($value)->getUrlObject()
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where would you initialize the breadcrumb variable to begin with?

Comment: @ref : https://www.drupal.org/node/2240003

Answer (score 7):

In case it help anyone I used a combination of Alex's solutions to write a function that returns the parent menu item for the current node.

```
function mymodule_get_parent_menu_title() {
  $menu_link_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.link');

  $node_id = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('node');
  if ($node_id) {
    $menu_link = $menu_link_manager->loadLinksByRoute('entity.node.canonical', array('node' => $node_id));
  }
  else {
    return '';
  }

  if (is_array($menu_link) && count($menu_link)) {
    $menu_link = reset($menu_link);
    if ($menu_link->getParent()) {
      $parents = $menu_link_manager->getParentIds($menu_link->getParent());
      $parent = reset(array_reverse($parents));
      $title = $menu_link_manager->createInstance($parent)->getTitle();

      return $title;
    }
  }

  return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, this code works but I doubt that this is the most performant way of doing it...

```
$node_id = $node->id();
$menu_link_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.link');
$menu_link = $menu_link_manager->loadLinksByRoute('entity.node.canonical', array('node' => $node_id));

if (is_array($menu_link) && count($menu_link)) {
  $menu_link = reset($menu_link);
  if ($menu_link->getParent()) {
    $parents = $menu_link_manager->getParentIds($menu_link->getParent());
    if (is_array($parents) && count($parents)) {
      $_parents = array();
      foreach ($parents as $key => $uuid) {
        $uuid_parts = explode(':', $uuid);
        $_parents[] = array_pop($uuid_parts);
      }

      $mlc_ids = \Drupal::database()
        ->select('menu_link_content', 'mlc')
        ->fields('mlc', ['id'])
        ->condition('uuid', $_parents, 'IN')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchCol();

      if (is_array($mlc_ids) && count($mlc_ids)) {
        $titles = \Drupal::database()
          ->select('menu_link_content_data', 'mlcd')
          ->fields('mlcd', ['title', 'link__uri'])
          ->condition('id', $mlc_ids, 'IN')
          ->execute()
          ->fetchAllKeyed();

        foreach ($titles as $title => $entityUri) {
          $breadcrumb->addLink(new Link($title, Url::fromUri($entityUri)));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

edit: but this does not even add menu items that do not come from nodes (for instance from views). See my other answer!

Answer (score 0):

Alex, your previous code works well, thanks !

For making it works with views or other routes, you have to use :

```
  $route_name = \Drupal::service('current_route_match')->getRouteName();
```

instead of using the node's route

Something like

```
$menu_link_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.link');

  $node_id = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('node');

  if ($node_id) {
    $menu_link = $menu_link_manager->loadLinksByRoute('entity.node.canonical', array('node' => $node_id));
  }
  else {
    $route_name = \Drupal::service('current_route_match')->getRouteName();
    $menu_link = $menu_link_manager->loadLinksByRoute($route_name);
  }
```